# Function to remove vowels fails edge case only

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *disemvowel(const char *str) {
    char vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    int len = strlen(str), i, j, k = 0, flag;
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
  
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        flag = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            if (str[i] == vowels[j])
                flag = 0;
        if (flag) {
            buf[k] = str[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    buf[k] = '\0';
    buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf));

    return buf;
}
```

The function correctly takes vowels out of input strings, but the tester code (from codewars) outputs this error:

```
The expression (as strings) (actual) == (expected) is false: 
actual=`dKwQMWGzMGtMFbvLJpnBRQXgZvRynrqVmzjklqgcpyngYdfWbKLhhZrhrTGFpdyPDNQNlnfgKWtRdGdcTqBWMkHKnCvpyLXqrVHKWlqfFxMqrkDjxNPmhtqFqvVCwNwqGftCHxnPRnPxyHgmdkTRnGtb1` 
expected=`dKwQMWGzMGtMFbvLJpnBRQXgZvRynrqVmzjklqgcpyngYdfWbKLhhZrhrTGFpdyPDNQNlnfgKWtRdGdcTqBWMkHKnCvpyLXqrVHKWlqfFxMqrkDjxNPmhtqFqvVCwNwqGftCHxnPRnPxyHgmdkTRnGtb`.
```

I don't know the input for this error, but the issue seems to be caused by the last character of the returned buffer. Any other input passed the test. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: it seems like numbers are not allowed either. Maybe you should consider whitelisting alphabet characters before removing vowels

Comment: it seems like numbers are not allowed either. Maybe you should consider whitelisting alphabet characters before removing vowels

Comment: If there are no vowels in the original string `char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);` does not allocate space for the `'\0'`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Even if there are vowels, `buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf));` is a good way to crash a program later on.

Comment: Not a solution, but it would also probably be a good idea to break your check out into a function. Something like `isvowel`. It would help to clean up your code and make it easier to reason about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but the issue seems to be caused by the last character of the returned buffer.

At least this problem:

**Off by 1**

OP's code allocations do not account for space needed by the *null character*.  `strlen()` reports a string's *length*, not including the *null character*.  An allocation needs to account for the *size* of a string, which does include *null character*.

```
// char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 1));

// buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf));
buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
```

---

Other issues include:

- Not checking for allocation failure.
- Using `int` rather than `size_t` to handle very long strings.
- Inefficient, code already knows the length.

  ```
    buf[k] = '\0';
    // buf = realloc(buf, strlen(buf) + 1);  // With corrected + 1
    buf = realloc(buf, k + 1);
  ```
- Inefficient: Once a vowel is found, no need to look for more,

  ```
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)

      // if (str[i] == vowels[j]) flag = 0;
      if (str[i] == vowels[j]) {
        flag = 0;
        break;
      }
  ```
- Inconsistent to scale by `size(char)` in one allocation, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the issues listed by *chux*, I spotted this one:

- potential memory leak: if `realloc(buf, ...)` fails, you return a null pointer and forget to free `buf`, which is no longer accessible. You should store the return value into another variable and return that or `buf` if `realloc` fails.

To avoid this and minimize fragmentation, you could first count the number of non vowels, then allocate the destination array, then iterate to copy the non vowels. This can be done efficiently with a lookup table:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *disemvowel(const char *str) {
    static char const isvowel[(unsigned char)-1 + 1] = {
        ['A'] = 1, ['E'] = 1, ['I'] = 1, ['O'] = 1, ['U'] = 1, 
        ['a'] = 1, ['e'] = 1, ['i'] = 1, ['o'] = 1, ['u'] = 1,
    };
    size_t i, k;
    unsigned char c;
    for (i = k = 0; (c = str[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        k += !isvowel[c];
    }
    char *buf = malloc(k + 1);
    if (buf != NULL) {
        for (i = k = 0; (buf[k] = c = str[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
            k += !isvowel[c];
        }
    }
    return buf;
}
```